# Dá para fazer um tipo de "setInterval()" no PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, setinterval

Para executar determinada função em um intervalo de tempo.

Comment: Mais fácil seria executar um PHP de tempos em tempos, pela crontab do linux ou agendador do windows.

Comment: Ajudaria um pouco se a pergunta trouxesse mais contexto e.g. que tipo de atividade se pretende fazer regularmente.

Comment: @epx Obrigado pela atenção, mas esta  pergunta tem mais de 3 anos. Não lembro mais do contexto em que fiz ela.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP não tem isso nativo. Nem faz sentido. Quando precisa algo assim e as aplicações em PHP raramente precisam disto, além de ser comum os programadores optarem por um mecanismo errado para sua necessidade, é melhor agendar tarefa no sistema operacional para chamar o *script* desejado. Deixar algo rodando e disparando não vai funcionar bem, ou mesmo funcionar, em ambiente web há um tempo limite curto que o *script* pode rodar

Mas se quiser saber dá para criar uma função que faça isso, algo assim:

```
function setInterval($callback, $milliseconds) {
    $seconds = (int)$milliseconds / 1000;
    while (true) {
        $callback();
        sleep($seconds);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Algorithm/SetInterval.php).

Mas é bem ruim fazer isso, não faça.